# is there a pandas function for evaluating values in different columns with a rolling function?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setting up the dataframe
data = [
          ['day 1','day 2', 2, 50],
          ['day 2','day 4', 2, 60],
          ['day 3','day 3', 1, 45],
          ['day 4','day 7', 2, 45],
          ['day 5','day 10', 3, 90],
          ['day 6','day 7', 3, 10],
          ['day 7','day 8', 2, 10]
]

columns = ['invoicedate', 'paymentdate', 'clientid', 'amounts']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

I have the above dataframe, and I want to check if the last invoice of a certain client ('clientid') was paid ('paymentdate') before a new invoice was issued ('invoicedate').

does anyone have a good (pandas?) solution for this? I tried some thing with the .rolling() function.

Answer (score 0):

This is less technology and more business modelling

- really you are looking at accounting concepts
- an approach is to consider the data as payables and receivables
- then you can run whatever rolling functions you want after modelling using these basic accounting business concepts

```
# setting up the dataframe
data = [
          ['day 1','day 2', 2, 50],
          ['day 2','day 4', 2, 60],
          ['day 3','day 3', 1, 45],
          ['day 4','day 7', 2, 45],
          ['day 5','day 10', 3, 90],
          ['day 6','day 7', 3, 10],
          ['day 7','day 8', 2, 10]
]

columns = ['invoicedate', 'paymentdate', 'clientid', 'amounts']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

# make abstract dates actual dates
cols = [c for c in df.columns if "date" in c]
df.loc[:,cols] = df.loc[:,cols].applymap(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(f'{d.split(" ")[1]}-jan-2021'))

# give it an invoice id...
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns={"index":"invoiceid"})
# make a payables / receivables structure
dfpr = pd.concat([df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c!="paymentdate"]].rename(columns={"invoicedate":"date"}).assign(type="pay"),
           df.loc[:,[c for c in df.columns if c!="invoicedate"]].rename(columns={"paymentdate":"date"}).assign(
               type="rec",amounts=lambda dfa: dfa.amounts*-1),
          ]).sort_values(["clientid","date"]).reset_index(drop=True)

# analysis - what does client owe..
dfpr.assign(rolling=dfpr.groupby(["clientid"]).agg({"amounts":"cumsum"}))
```

|  | invoiceid | date | clientid | amounts | type | rolling |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | 45 | pay | 45 |
| 1 | 2 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 1 | -45 | rec | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 2 | 50 | pay | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | 60 | pay | 110 |
| 4 | 0 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 2 | -50 | rec | 60 |
| 5 | 3 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | 45 | pay | 105 |
| 6 | 1 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00 | 2 | -60 | rec | 45 |
| 7 | 6 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 | 10 | pay | 55 |
| 8 | 3 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 2 | -45 | rec | 10 |
| 9 | 6 | 2021-01-08 00:00:00 | 2 | -10 | rec | 0 |
| 10 | 4 | 2021-01-05 00:00:00 | 3 | 90 | pay | 90 |
| 11 | 5 | 2021-01-06 00:00:00 | 3 | 10 | pay | 100 |
| 12 | 5 | 2021-01-07 00:00:00 | 3 | -10 | rec | 90 |
| 13 | 4 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | 3 | -90 | rec | 0 |

Comment: Hi Rob, I am so sorry..  I forgot to mention that I have a column with the amount of days it took the customer to pay the invoice.. Thanks anyway for your answer. it helped me understand the problem better ;)